# Allowing CFFILE and CFFTP to work within the same CFFORM

Tags: coldfusion, forms

I am using a shared hosting server that limits the filesize (let's say 100 MB) for CFFILE Action="Upload" - my code works for 99% of all uploads, but on files that are larger than 100 MB, they recommend that I use FTP.

In order for CFFTP to work, I need the local pathname (i.e. "c:\myFiles\fileToUpload.mpg"), but because I'm using the CFFORM ENCYTYPE="multipart/form-data" if I dump the formfield, it is listed as a .tmp on the server. If I eliminate the ENCTYPE designation, then I get the local pathname, and I'm good to go.

My goal is to switch to CFFTP if the filesize exceeds 100 MB seamlessly. Is it possible to extract the local pathname when the ENCTYPE is set to "multipart/form-data" ?

OR is there some other way to allow CFFTP and CFFILE to work in this way?

Here's an abstraction of how I'd like to see things work:

```
<!--- perform actions --->
<cfif isdefined("FORM.fileToUpload")>
    <cfif fileSizeInMB(FORM.fileToUpload) < 100>
        <cffile action="upload" blah blah>
    <cfelse>
        <cfftp action="putfile" blah blah>
    </cfif>
</cfif>

<!--- show page --->
<cfform action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
    <input type="submit" />
</cfform>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Forms don't do FTP upload. You need to get your users to connect with an FTP client (e.g. [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org)), and come up with a system for linking that to the application.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: You'd have to use a client-side FTP client like a Java, Flash, ActiveX Control, etc. to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, I guess I should have read the CF documentation more closely: "Use this tag to move files between a ColdFusion server and an FTP server."

Comment: @JasonD - Small aside, `action="upload"` is something of a misnomer. The file is already uploaded to the server before you ever hit the action page. The `cffile` call simply moves and renames the file (the actual uploading is done long before that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ColdFusion documentation, the CFFTP tag is used to "... move files between a ColdFusion server and an FTP server." - this tag does not allow you to read from a client's hard drive to upload to the server. The only way to transfer files from the client is with CFFILE.

In my situation, I will have to let the client know that there is now a restriction on the size of files to upload - per Dan's suggestion, I will recommend the use of Firezilla to upload all files over 100 MB.

Thanks to all for your responses.

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe the 100 MB limit is a ColdFusion restriction that is set via the administrator (although your web server will/should also have a limit). Further, I believe that ColdFusion has been setup that way for a while (at least a few versions back).  I know that Adobe made some changes regarding large file handling in ColdFusion 8.  Anyway I also wanted to share a good article from [Pete Freitag regarding secure file uploads with ColdFusion](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm) where he also mentions these settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck for a couple of reasons.  First, getting a local filepath without the user's express consent isn't going to happen.  There are active x controls you can write that do this, but the browser will ask the user if he wants to permit it.  Consider that unlikely.

Next, cfftp will only work with machines that are ftp enabled.  Most personal computers are not.  Those that are might have security measures for you to overcome.

I think the best you can do if the file is too big is to display a message stating so to the user.  This message would have information about ftp clients such as Filezilla, and instructions on how to ftp files to the server, assuming of course that the owner of the server will allow the general public to ftp files in.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! The user is selecting the local file to upload, all he is doing is clicking the "Browse" button that is automatically generated by the <input type="file"> tag. If I did not include the enctype, then I would have the local path, no problem.

Comment: My fallback position is to let the user know that he won't be able to upload files over a certain size, but I am trying to avoid this, as there were no limitations in the past (it looks like my hosting provider began enforcing CFFILE upload limits within the past year).